# Prime factorization of integers with Maxima

Tags: maxima

I want to use Maxima to get the prime factorization of a random positive integer, e.g. 12=2^2*3^1.

What I have tried so far:

```
a:random(20);
aa:abs(a);
fa:ifactors(aa);
ka:length(fa);
ta:1;
pfza: for i:1 while i<=ka do ta:ta*(fa[i][1])^(fa[i][2]);
ta;
```

This will be implemented in STACK for Moodle as part of a online exercise for students, so the exact implementation will be a little bit different from this, but I broke it down to these 7 lines.

I generate a random number a, make sure that it is a positive integer by using aa=|a|+1 and want to use the ifactors command to get the prime factors of aa. ka tells me the number of pairwise distinct prime factors which I then use for the while loop in pfza. If I let this piece of code run, it returns everything fine, execpt for simplifying ta, that is I don't get ta as a product of primes with some exponents but rather just ta=aa.

I then tried to turn off the simplifier, manually simplifying everything else that I need:

```
simp:false$
a:random(20);
aa:ev(abs(a),simp);
fa:ifactors(aa);
ka:ev(length(fa),simp);
ta:1;
pfza: for i:1 while i<=ka do ta:ta*(fa[i][1])^(fa[i][2]);
ta;
```

This however does not compile; I assume the problem is somewhere in the line for pfza, but I don't know why.

Any input on how to fix this? Or another method of getting the factorizing in a non-simplified form?

Answer (score 1):

(1) The for-loop fails because adding 1 to `i` requires `1 + 1` to be simplified to 2, but simplification is disabled. Here's a way to make the loop work without requiring arithmetic.

```
(%i10) for f in fa do ta:ta*(f[1]^f[2]);
(%o10)                          done
(%i11) ta;
                                2   2   1
(%o11)                     ((1 2 ) 2 ) 3
```

Hmm, that's strange, again because of the lack of simplification. How about this:

```
(%i12) apply ("*", map (lambda ([f], f[1]^f[2]), fa));
                                 2  1
(%o12)                          2  3
```

In general I think it's better to avoid explicit indexing anyway.

(2) But maybe you don't need that at all. `factor` returns an unsimplified expression of the kind you are trying to construct.

```
(%i13) simp:true;
(%o13)                          true
(%i14) factor(12);
                                 2
(%o14)                          2  3
```

I think it's conceptually inconsistent for `factor` to return an unsimplified, but anyway it seems to work here.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. One problem is, that I am doing this with STACK, which is basically Maxima, but with some twists. If I use factor(12), I only get 12 as the result. So I tried to come up with my solution in my question. However, somehow I did not think about using factor() with simplification turned off, which then works fine in STACK. Do you have a suggestion on how I could make it look more like a product, as in using/showing a multiplication dot between the different prime factors?

Comment: Re: "If I use factor(12), I only get 12 as the result." -- I guess simplification is somehow being applied to the results from Maxima; since the result of `factor` is an unsimplified expression, it's fragile in the sense the resimplification will undo it. Re: how to show multiplication, see the display flag `stardisp`. If you want to change the multiplication sign from an asterisk to something else, we can try to do that too, let me know if you want to go down that road.

Comment: stardisp is so far not a usable command in STACK, I will see if one can implement that and expand the list of usable Maxima commands, thank you very much!